# <a> link color CSS not working for Chrome/Firefox/IE/Safari etc

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, colour-depth, anchor

Here is my site: http://dosrevival.com

I can't seem to get the links to stop turning purple after being clicked in Chrome and IE (works in some Firefox versions?!?). In my CSS file I'm changing the a:link and a:hover 'color' to white and the 'text-decoration' to none or underlined as necessary. What's making Chrome throw this back up? Thanks!

Comment: HTML/CSS questions are a better fit on [Doctype](http://doctype.com)

Answer (score 4):

Check out this link
http://blogs.x2line.com/al/articles/159.aspx

Basically you need something along these lines

```
a:link              { color:red; }
a:visited           { color:green; }
a:hover             { color:blue; }
a:active            { color:orange; }
```

Notice that I didn't put purple in there.  You can see each color in the life cycle of the click process.

#### ALSO

It is **VERY** important that you put them in the [proper order](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2003/04/order_of_anchor.html).  Link, Visited, Hover, Active

Comment: I've looked at the CSS and the link specification is in fact in the wrong order. The way that I learned to remember it was with LoVe HAte. Link, Visited, Hover, Active.

Comment: The link in the comment of the Adobe blog has the best explanation IMO: http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/link-specificity.html

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to check the specifity. Sometimes you might have set a:visited for whole Body, or just a general redefine, so it has more weight. I often just use a parent id (IDs have more weight than classes) like `#container whateverClasss a:visited {color:#000;}` . Adding a !important; might also work, but imo is worse. Keeping an order in general is best.

Comment: Yes, you should just use order. Use `!important` only as a measure of last resort since it can seriously inhibit the maintainability and comprehensibility of your CSS. Using it out of laziness or to avoid proper debugging/planning is a bad habit.